# Is it possible to receive notifications after the app has been removed from the app store?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that is integrated with Localytics push notifications service and this app will be discontinued and my company wants still to be able to reach to those customers and send push notifications.

Now, if I remove the app from the app store. Would it be possible still to send those users who already have the app a push notification using again Localytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some apps which are not available in the app store for my country anymore but I still receiving pushes from them. So I think it is not a problem to receive such notifications until the developer certificate expire. Also you can receive such notifications from main apple push notifications service before app is published on the app store. So I think you will be able to send such notifications for some time.